# Select table td value inside iframe with jquery

Tags: jquery, wordpress, iframe, html-table

I am trying to do this for an hours. I have found may suggestions here and there and none of them work.

```
 <button id="dugme" type="button">Click Me!</button>

<iframe id="frm" src="http://www.kursna-lista.info/resources/kursna-lista.php?format=3&datum=1" width="260px" height="130px" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>
```

this is what I have inside my wordpress page.
I know iframe is its own DOM or something like that and I tried a lot of suggestions I found online but non of them work.

Last thing I tried was this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
var target_document = $('#frm')[0].contentWindow.document;
var target_result   = $(target_document).find('table');
$('#dugme').on('click', function() {
alert(target_result.html());
});
```

});

Can anybody help me with this, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have no luck modern browsers recognize this for a good reason as Cross Site Scripting.

Imagine you go on a page of an author and in an invisible iframe the author buys 20 books on amazon for you. Just via jscript clicks and because you are logged in to amazon on another tab.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do that as far as I know. Basically in an iframe, you are accessing a different URL which is part of another application. Browser, as a security policy, would not allow you to access objects from different domains. Cross site content cannot be read - XSS protection.